# when user clicks the 'Pay' button, I want to check first that the seat they are purchasing is still available before completing the purchase (stripe)

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm using the stripe iframe for checkout on a platform that sells course seats. I want to avoid a situation where 2 clients are getting to the payment screen simultaneously and both are able to purchase the same seat, so I need validation to occur at the moment of checkout when the user clicks on 'Pay' (I don't want to prevent clients from purchasing the seat as long as the seat is not fully paid and taken - first one to click 'Pay' wins). but I can't edit anything in the stripe iframe. is there any way to perform such kind of validation?

Answer (score 0):

Usually what's inside an iFrame is completely out of control of the caller; you should check the documentation or ask someone from Stripe to see if there's a way to do this (usually payment-system providers offer a more direct integration option).

Aditionally, a way that I've seen most ticket sellers work is to "temporarily assign" the selected seat to the customer (i.e. as soon as someone selects a seat it becomes unavailable to others) but they give the customer a limited time (around 5 minutes) to either complete or cancel the order; if the time runs out or the customer cancels then the seat becomes available again.

Comment: Stripe does not currently offer inventory tracking like so temporarily assigning the selected seat and giving the user a limited time to claim it is typically the recommendation here.

Comment: To cancel a Checkout Session order, make the Expire a Checkout Session call. To cancel a PaymentIntent, make the "Cancel a PaymentIntent" call[2]

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/expire
[2] https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/cancel